# Problems fully updating my system

Tags: apt, updates

Every time I try updating my system with `sudo apt-get update`, I'm prompted with this:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pasgui/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo apt-get update` doesn't actually update anything. It just refreshes Ubuntu's repositories, so it knows if updates are available. You need to run `sudo apt-get upgrade` to actually update any packages.

As for that error, it shouldn't affect much in terms of upgrades. Since it's obviously an invalid PPA, you can just remove it. Do that by running `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:pasgui/ppa`. Once you do that, you won't have any more annoying errors.

Answer (score 1):

[This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pasgui/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you have added does not provide packages for Xenial; you should remove it.

Comment: The answer is incomplete as long as you don't explain how to remove the PPA.

Comment: @ByteCommander One has to draw the line somewhere, otherwise any answer would be a full guide in using Ubuntu.

Comment: @fkraiem Explaining how to remove the PPA doesn't take much. I did it in my answer in what could be one sentence.

Comment: You could at least link another question on Ask Ubuntu that explains it. Or just look at the other answer by Zacharee, that's how it should be.

Comment: What do you mean the ppa doesn't provide packages for Xenial?

Comment: Im new to Linux. What do you mean the ppa doesn't provide packages for Xenial?

Comment: @MRG8851 it means that PPA doesn't have anything built to run on Ubuntu 16.04 (which is codenamed Xenial).

Comment: @ByteCommander "That's how it should be" is your opinion. My opinion is that the answer is fine as it is, otherwise I would have written it differently.